# How to validate email after text is entered in textfield Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am new in appcelerator. I have a doubt. Does anybody have any idea about how to check email validation after we entered text in text field. I can able to do by a button click. But what i want is that, need to check in text field itself after text is entered. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a event listener on textfield.

```
textField.addEventListener('return',function(e){
     if(isValidEmail(e.source.value)){
        //Email is valid
     }else{
        //Invalid Email
     }

});


function isValidEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj... it works for me. One more doubt. How do we check if the user pressed android back button. How do we check that condition ? I am new in appcelerator That's why

Comment: You can handle android back button by adding an event "androidback" listerner. please refer this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Event_Handling-section-29004896_EventHandling-SpecialEvents

Comment: Hi suraj, the scenario i meant is that, when we enter a text on text field the soft keyboard is visible and after entering, when the user hide soft keyboard by pressing android back button. How do we check validation in that case ? Do u have any idea about that ?